# JS Cross domain offline local storage

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that usually suppose to work offline.(without internet connection).
Once a while it's need to connect to the web and grab some data to be used offline.

I'm searching for a way to store the data locally while it connected and still have an access to the data offline.

I checked local storage and the [FileSystem-API](http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html) but both are follows the Same Origin Policy.

Any suggestion will be appreciate

Comment: Why are cross-origin restrictions a problem?

Comment: @gcampbell when the data is saved while being connected the domain is my host domain, but while running it offline there is no domain just a html file

Comment: @amichai Can you use PHP to when *online*?

Comment: @Justinas when im online im connecting to my server runs ASP.NET

Comment: You'll probably need to rethink your whole design because grabbing data from a different host is trivial with the correct design. Without at least a little idea of your code, I wouldn't even attempt to point out where you may have gone wrong

Comment: Take a look at tiddlywiki. They manage to do what you're trying to do: create an app in the form of an html file. But you will need to tell your users to reconfigure their browsers depending on the browser.

Comment: @slebetman Thanks, I'll look for it

Answer (score 0):

When I was creating offline application to sync with online version I had some JSON file with required information instead of LocalStorage.

Work flow:

1. User requests new files to be generated (a.k.a. sync with server) using some online interface.
2. Generate JSON file with needed data and save it along offline files.
3. User downloads new files and replaces it with old ones.
4. Offline JS reads JSON file and gets all information.

We were using some JAVA installer ([launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to generate *.jar* files and [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) to make installer)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that the offline page have no access to local file system